# callback returns value but apears to be undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am new to node and callbacks. I was trying to split a list of groups into an array. the groups are seperated with comma's or with "-". This last one means it is an interval so if there is 22-25 it means: 22, 23, 24, 25. I tried the following code.

```
var groups = ["13-16","21-24","33"];
var splitgroups = function(groups, callback){
   var result = [];
   console.log(groups.length);
   for(var i=0; i<groups.length; i++){
     var cbr = callback(groups[i]);
     result = result.concat(cbr);
   }
  return result;
}

var handlegroupinterval = function(group){
  var temparr = [];
  try {
    temparr = group.split('-');
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
  console.log("groups split: "+group);
  if(temparr.length>1){
      var lowerbound = parseInt(temparr[0]);
      var upperbound = parseInt(temparr[1]);  
      temparr = [];
      for(var j=lowerbound; j<=upperbound; j++){
        temparr.push(j);
      }  
  }    
  return temparr;
}
var tempgroups = splitgroups(groups, function(res){handlegroupinterval(res)});
console.log("end: " +tempgroups);
```

when I set a breakpoint on the "return temparr" I get the proper values. But in the first function result is thee times undefined. someone knows the problem?

Comment: OMG you're right. Thanks, just a return fixed it! thanks alot.

Answer (score 5):

You do not `return` from the callback.

Simply replace

```
var tempgroups = splitgroups(groups, function(res){handlegroupinterval(res)});
```

with

```
var tempgroups = splitgroups(groups, function(res){ return handlegroupinterval(res); });
```

Notice the added `return` in the callback.

Also, I think you could further simplify this as

```
var tempgroups = splitgroups(groups, handlegroupinterval);
```